# I'm trying to connect mysql through JDBC on mac osx

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, macos, jdbc

My IDE is Eclipse Indigo. I get this when I was trying to connect:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And here is my code.

```
public class TPCH
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String userName = "tpch";
        String password = "tpch";
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", password);

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/",
                           connectionProps);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error connecting to db");
        }
    }
}
```

I think JDBC is not imported. I tried to import it by

```
preference -> java -> build path -> user library -> add jars
```

But I still got that exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you add JARs to the classpath in Eclipse.

You have to right-click on your project, select `Java Build Path > Libraries` and add a JAR file. For MySQL, you'd need the [MySQL Connector J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

[image]